# How do I customize nginx on AWS elastic beanstalk to loadbalance Meteor?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running Meteor on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everything is up and running except that it's not running Websockets with the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://MYDOMAIN/sockjs/834/sxx0k7vn/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket     handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

My unstanding was to add something like:

`proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";`

To the proxy config, via my YML config file.

Via my .exbextension config file:

```
files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection      "upgrade";
```

I have ssh'd into the server and I can see the proxy.conf with those two lines in it.

When I hit my webserver I still see the "Error during WebSocket handshake: " error.

I have my beanstalk load configured with stick sessions and the following ports:

[image]
[image]

BTW I did see https://meteorhacks.com/load-balancing-your-meteor-app.html and I tried to:

`Enable HTTP load balancing with Sticky Session on Port 80
Enable TCP load balancing on Port 8080, which allows websocket`

But could not seem to get that working either.

Adding another shot at some YAML that does NOT work here": https://gist.github.com/adamgins/0c0258d6e1b8203fd051

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a LOT of help from AWS paid support, I got this working. The reality is I was not far off it was down to some SED syntaxt.

Here's what currently works ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/adamgins/f99635447a1239289460)):

```
option_settings:

  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: <SOMESECRET>

  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: <SOMEKEY>

  - option_name: PORT
    value: 8081

  - option_name: ROOT_URL
    value: <SOMEURL>

  - option_name: MONGO_URL
    value: <SOMEMONGOURL>

    - option_name: MONGO_OPLOG_URL
    value: <SOMEMONGOURL>

  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: ProxyServer
    value: nginx

    option_name: GzipCompression
    value: true

  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles

    option_name: /public
    value: /public

    container_commands:

  01_nginx_static:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
        ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

In addition to this you need to got into your Load balancer and change the Listener from HTTP to TCP:

[image]

described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html).

Comment: Note I do have one open issue. I had to disable sticky sessions when swapping the protocol to TCP. I have an open question to understand if I get this back on.

Comment: OK, the discussion of how important websockets is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/M6L_Ihpu-e0 if you have any input please jump in

Comment: I currently have a dev/staging instance in ebs with no load balancer configured (scaling option is set to "single instance").  I presume this means I don't need to bother with that step?

Comment: yep - the qyestion comes when you want to scale. It looks like opsworks or custom EC2 are only valid options right now... I am still working on it. It looks like I will need to build a custom proxy layer with either NGINX or HAPROXY as the out of the box HAPROXY on Opswork wont do it either... ahhh  I can't wait to get this sorted out ... or until AWS starts supporting this out of the box on Beanstalk (hint ;-) )

Comment: I ended up moving to use opsworks, cluster and docker as per https://blog.sunsama.com/meteor-docker-opsworks/

Comment: I've just upvoted for just sharing your 'paid' help tricks with us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Meteor WebSocket handshake error 400 with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014969/meteor-websocket-handshake-error-400-with-nginx?rq=1)? I think their configuration might be a bit different from yours. I'm in the same boat as you, trying to get this exact same set up working.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yep, I had seen this but this is a straight EC2 (not Beanstalk) example. I know what has to happen to the config file to make it work... I just can't seem to get the YAML Config right to get it to take. I am thinking I may need to use SED instead to try and update the existing NGINX config files vs append/add to them. So I think I am asking more about syntax vs what actually needs to be done.

Comment: I opened a paid support call with AWS yesterday... so will see what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works. I posted more here https://solitaired.com/websockets-elastic-beanstalk but the jist is create a file in `.ebextensions` (called `websockets.config` for example) with the following:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf":
    content: |

      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: I have just deployed a beanstalk and the websockets work fine without the config file. Is it still needed? (The deploy fails when I try adding this config file.)